# Meaning of 託す here

Tags: meaning, words, word-usage

What does 託されて mean in this passage? I see that it can mean "to express in the form of" or "to use as a pretext". Is one of those definitions applicable?

> ⁠　とまれ古い昔にどこかの遥かな国の王子が、黄金の船に乗ってこの島に流れついた。王子は島の娘を娶り、死んだのちは陵に埋められたのである。王子の生涯が何の口碑も残さず、附会され仮託されがちなどんな悲劇的な物語もその王子に**託されて**語られなかったということは、たとえこの伝説が事実であったにしろ、おそらく歌島での王子の生涯が、物語を生む余地もないほどに幸福なものだったということを暗示する。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[託す](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%A8%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/#jn-135885) has the following definitions:

> １ 自分がなすべきことを他の人に頼む。まかせる。「後事を友人に―・する」
>
> ２ 人に頼んで品物などを届けてもらう。用件を他の人にことづける。「伝言を―・する」
>
> ３ 気持ちや意見などを他の物にことよせて表す。「思いのたけを歌に―・する」

The meaning you mention and the usage in question are both 3.

I guess XをYに託す= to express X in the form of Y (like 思いのたけを歌に託す above) works, but obfuscates the original meaning of attaching/passing on X. Just as 息子を両親に託す means *to leave a son to parents*, 思いを歌に託す has a connotation that 思い is passed on/conveyed by 歌.

So 附会され...語られなかった literally means *tragic stories that are likely to be attached (to such a person) was not passed on (and told) **attached to the prince***. (In this case, 附会する/仮託する/託す are practically synonymous.)